# StartDate EndDate validation with Angularjs and Bootstrape datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

This is My HTML

```
 <form name="myForm">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input data-ng-model="Data.StartDate" type="text" id="startDate"   name="startDate"
            class="form-control" data-datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" data-datepicker-append-to-body="true"
            data-is-open="popup.fromOpened" data-ng-click="fromOpen()" placeholder="Start Date" data-ng-required="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input data-ng-model="Data.EndDate" type="text" id="endDate" name="endDate"
            class="form-control" data-datepicker-popup="MM-dd-yyyy" data-datepicker-append-to-body="true"
            data-is-open="popup.toOpened" data-ng-click="toOpen()" placeholder="End Date" data-ng-required="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <button data-ng-click="Search()" class="btn btn-info">Search</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <span>Error list</span>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Angular code is like this.

```
 $scope.$watch('Data.StartDate', validateDates);
$scope.$watch('Data.EndDate', validateDates);

function validateDates() {
//      some code and highlight it on form
}
```

I would like to add some decent validation for dates in my page. any help will appreciated..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just write type="date" in html input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Code you wrote as example via '$watch' is pretty unsupportable and hard to maintain. In case of adding new fields, you will just make a 500+ like controller.

I suggest to you to create:

1. `ValidationFactory` that will contain validation methods for all types;
2. `FIELDS_CONFIG` Object where you will store `{fieldName: 'string', validationErrorMessage: 'string', fieldType: 'string', validateIf: 'function', value: {} //path to another factory, where field origin value stored}`;
3. Directive that will execute validation only at dedicated `form`, `div` etc, and `$watch` entire model that you will provide to it;
4. Moving all properties to dedicated `form` model object.

So once something changed in `model`, directive will execute validation method from `ValidationFactory` based on `fieldType`, that will use `value` to pass to taht method. The result of validation will be stored at `ValidationFactory.errors = {}` with keys as `fieldName` to easily access errors to show `validationErrorMessage`.

Simpler approach that is somehow anti-pattern is:

`ng-change` directive to each field you want to validate. `ng-change` will accept `ValidationFactory.validateDate(value, message)`. All errors should be stored at `ValidationFactory.errors = []` to have access point to check `ValidationFactory.isAnyErrors()` from parent controllers etc.